# Move resource to new directory

Tags: c#, .net, path, resources, embedded-resource

i have a resource file (`ConvertColorValues.dll`) located within the `Resource` folder in my c# application, now my question is how would i move this file to a new directory on users computer?

I've tried this but it does not seem to be working:

```
File.Move(MyApp.Properties.Resources.ConvertColorValues, @"C:\Users\User\Documents");
```

How can i achieve what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the context of where you are running the applicaion.  I am assuming you are using a client based application such as WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to move an embedded resource as its contained in the assembly.  Try copying it.